# The probability that $x$ is divisible by $p$ where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in\mathbb{P}$

Tags: probability, divisibility

The probability that $x$ is divisible by $p$ is $\frac{1}{p}$ for an integer $x$ and a prime $p$. Firstly, the probability should be some decreasing function, like $2^{-p}$ or $\frac{p}{p-1}$, but I don't understand why it's only just $\frac{1}{p}$.

Secondly, I don't understand why the probability doesn't depend on $x$. It means that the probability that $1$ is divisible by $2$ is the same as the probability that $1024$ is divisible by $2$, which I find nonsensical.

Comment: Because in every $p$ consecutive integers exactly one of them is divisible by p.

Comment: "Secondly, I don't understand why the probability doesn't depend on x." If you *know*  $x$ there is no probability here - $x$ is either divisible by $p$ or it isn't. The statement is: if I pick a natural number $x$ between $1$ and $n$ uniformly at random, then what's the limit of the probability that $x$ is divisible by $p$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{p}$ is the probability that an integer which is drawn randomly from $\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible by $p$, as soon as you give a specific value to $x$ there is no randomness, so it doesn't make sense to talk about "the probability of 1 being divisible by 2"

Comment: @CBowman what does it mean to randomly draw an integer from $\mathbb{Z}$ though?

Comment: @hunter that's a good point, I don't know if there is a way to define that selection as a valid probability distribution. Speaking about it in terms of the limit as the maximum allowed integer value goes to infinity as WoolierThanThou does in their comment seems to be a better way to view things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to say that this is a heuristic and that your criticism of the heuristic is reasonable. However, another reasonable interpretation of "the probability that a random natural number is divisible by $p$" is
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}  \frac{\text{numbers less than }N \text{ divisible by p}}{\text{all numbers less than }N} = \frac{1}{p}
$$
which is of course true. Since the heuristic can be useful, it's worth entertaining it, keeping in mind that its meaningfulness depends on some pretty deep questions in philosophy of math.

Comment: But actually there were *integers* in the question.

Comment: @PoderRac good point, you could add "with absolute value less than $N$" to numerator and denominator